# setTickFormat doesn't work with Primefaces CatagoryAxis

Tags: jsf, primefaces, charts

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces LineChartModel to create a Histogram with probability density function overlapped, that looks Something like this: 
[image]

To achieve that I followed this example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/multiaxis.xhtml

You can ignore top X axis I don't need any label there and I will eventually remove them.

I want to format labels at the bottom X axis to include up to 3 decimal places.

X axis at the picture is defined in this way:

```
    Axis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setTickFormat("%1$.3f");
```

If instead CategoryAxis I use Linear axis:

```
    Axis xAxis = new LinearAxis();
    xAxis.setTickFormat("%1$.3f");
```

this is what I get:

[image]

Axis is formatted alright but the chart just collapses.

Is there a way to format Categorical Axis to include 3 decimal places?